# Java equivalent of C fscanf

Tags: java, c, arrays, scanf

I want to find out what is the similar or exact function in Java.

For Example in C,

```
    fscanf(file_Qpointer, "%s", BenchmarkQ[jj].owner);
```

In the example above, the array has a "**.owner**" behind and I have been reading on Java Array API but I couldn't find anything related to it. I am new to Java as well and could have miss it while reading the API. Can anyone enlighten on what could the function be in Java.

This is in a for loop where I read from a document that contains information that i wanted in a order and store each line into a array.

```
    queryvalue BenchmarkQ[500];
    FILE *file_Qpointer;    
    if ((file_Qpointer =fopen("query", "r"))==NULL)
    {
        //printf("no such file!\n");
        exit(-1);
    }
    else
        rewind(file_Qpointer);

    for (jj=0; jj<500;jj++)
    {
        fscanf(file_Qpointer, "%s",     BenchmarkQ[jj].owner);
        printf("%s\n",BenchmarkQ[jj].owner);
        fscanf(file_Qpointer, "%s",     BenchmarkQ[jj].ext);
        printf("%s\n",BenchmarkQ[jj].ext);      
    }
```

Comment: this question needs more Java context. Java files, arrays and strings are a whole different world compared to C.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a piece of code that illustrate the use of Scanner in Java.

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class TestScanner {

    public static class BenchmarkQ {
        public String owner;
        public String ext;
        public int filesize;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int count = 2;
        BenchmarkQ[] benchs = new BenchmarkQ[count];

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        for (int jj = 0; jj < count; jj++) {
            benchs[jj] = new BenchmarkQ();
            benchs[jj].owner = sc.next(); // Equivalent of %s
            System.out.printf("Owner '%s'\n", benchs[jj].owner);
            benchs[jj].ext = sc.next();
            System.out.printf("Ext '%s'\n", benchs[jj].ext);
            benchs[jj].filesize = sc.nextInt(); // Equivalent of %d
            System.out.printf("Filesize '%d'\n", benchs[jj].filesize);
        }

        sc.close();
    }

}
```

Check the documentation of Scanner:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html

Comment: Hi @Delphin, Where do you get the BenmarqQ[] from? I couldn't initialise it. I also looked through the documentation of Scanner but there wasn't anything related to BenchmarqQ. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi @user3414091, BenchmarkQ is not part of the Java library. I consider this is part of user class or libraries so I declared BenchmarkQ directly in the example. BencharkQ[] array is created in main and filled with BenchmarkQ elements in the loop.

Comment: BenchmarkQ class in my Java example stands for queryvalue type in your C example. Since we don't have details on queryvalue type, you have to figure out were it is defined and find a corresponding type in Java library or make your own definition just like I did.

Answer (score 0):

Here `owner` is not a property of the array, but a member of `BenchmarkQ[jj]`, i.e. of the `jj`-th entry in `BenchmarkQ`. Please refer to the entry type of `queryvalue`. `queryvalue` seems to have some members `owner`, `ext` and `filesize`. Perhaps its definition is inside some library.

Comment: Hi @Codor, BenchmarkQ[ ] is declared as queryvalue BenchmarkQ[500];

Comment: @user3414091 please edit any additional info/code into your original question so everyone can see it

Comment: How do I add a member to a array in Java? Thanks!

Comment: @user3414091 Please show the definition of the type `queryvalue`.

Comment: @Codor I have made amends to my question. Sorry for the lack of information.